# Perl sprintf formatting of colored output

Tags: perl, colors, formatting, printf

How do I generate fixed width output in this statement ?

```
use Term::ANSIColor;
printf("%s",sprintf("[%8s]",colored(sprintf("\$%0.2f",$Price),'red')))
```

The `%8s` doesn't have any effect in this statement. Are there any color conscious format specifiers ?

Comment: What makes you think that strings that produce colours in terminals have any special property that makes them different from other strings?

Comment: I thought they were "special" and immune to format specifiers. And they are invisible too!

Comment: No. They are just processed by your terminal. Try printing them with `Data::Dumper` and you will see what they look like.

Comment: I am assuming, of course, that you are not using `sprintf` in void context and expecting output, but that you are doing something like `my $str = sprintf...; print $str;`.

Comment: Yes. I am concatenating many strings together along with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure it does, it's just that the codes that change the color on your terminal also have a width, and so the string you pass to the first `sprintf` call is already more than 8 characters. Try it with

```
sprintf("[%18s]", ...
```

and you'll see an affect.

But the width of terminal codes is esoteric, so you're better off moving the color coding outside of the fixed-width formattng.

```
printf("[%s]", colored( sprintf("%8s", sprintf("\$%0.2f",$Price) ),'red') )
```